# Can a verbum deponens go along with an accusativus?

Tags: classical-latin, verbs, accusative, deponent-verbs, plinius-minor

In Plinius I encountered:

> "Confitentes iterum ac tertio interrogavi **supplicium minatus**"

Is *supplicium* some sort of accusativus belonging to *minatus*, which comes from deponens *minor*?

If a form is passive then I would expect that the "accused" has taken his place as the subject already. But then suddenly another "accused" shows up. Somehow that bothers me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, a deponent verb can have an accusative object just like non-deponent verbs do.

If I threaten someone with something in Latin, then *alicui aliquid minor*.
The person (or other entity) being threatened is in dative, but the threat (death, punishment, fine, ...) is in accusative.
Since *minari* is a deponent verb, the seemingly passive form can be used as if it were active.
In my experience the non-deponent version *minare* is less common.

Therefore *interrogavi supplicium minatus* means "I interrogated and threatened with punishment".
The most natural translation of *supplicium* depends on context.

As a side note, *supplicium* is also the plural genitive of *supplex*, but this interpretation makes little sense in this context.

Comment: Thank you. That makes things clear. Even your side note is functional (if it is not accusative then what is it?...). I can drop this questioning now. A soon acceptance might cause less attention of others, so I postpone that. I allready know you from [Maths](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Only a side note: a better translation of _supplicium_ in this context is _torture._

Comment: Tibi gratulor, quod iam >centum milia punctorum tulisti! :)