# Can the verb auxiliari take an accusative object?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, grammar-choice, object

The verb *auxiliari* is used with dative to indicate the entity that benefits from the help.
For example, *tibi auxilior* means "I help you".
Can use an accusative object to express how the help is given?
For example, can I say *hoc tibi auxilior* to say "I help you by/in doing this"?
If such an object is possible, what exactly does it mean?

I have seen constructions like this, but they are somewhat rare, and I do not recall seeing *auxiliari* used this way.
To give a concrete example, *minari* can take an accusative object to indicate the content of the threat.
I previously explained in an answer to [another question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/130/79) that *hoc tibi minor* means "I threaten you with this".
I wonder how broadly accusative can be used in this fashion, whence the question.

Comment: By the way, *hoc* "with this, by this way" also works as an ablative...

Comment: @Cerberus, I know. This question comes from idle curiosity rather than trying to decipher a Latin text with *hoc auxiliari*. I thought of using *id* or some other such word, but *hoc* felt best.

Comment: OK just wanted to be sure! L&S give no examples with an accusative.

Comment: I don't have an example, but pronominal internal accusatives are productive enough in Latin (examples in [A&G](http://www.hhhh.org/perseant/libellus/aides/allgre/allgre.390.html)) that I'd guess this would probably be grammatical.

Answer (score 4):

Cassell's "Latin Dictionary" specifies `auxilior` can be used, as you said, with the dative, or in a construction with `contra` plus the accusative.  However, that's not really `auxilior` taking the accusative itself.

The construction you suggest as "I help you by/in doing this" sounds like it would be ablative of means by which, not accusative.

Short answer, I'd say, is that it cannot.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of an internal object or an internal accusative? It is about verbs that do not usually take objects taking objects, like *vitam vivere*. The question is about this kind of an internal object, especially a pronominal one. I agree that *auxiliari* almost never takes an accusative object, I am not yet convinced that it never does so. See TKR's comment above.

Comment: I haven't heard it called that, but Allen and Greensborough give the exact quote, `vitam vivere` under "cognate accusative."  It says that an intransitive verb may often take an acc. of a noun of kindred meaning.  It gives a couple of deponent verb examples under one section, saying that neuter pronouns or an adjective of indefinite meaning is common as cognate accusative, but the examples don't make me think that this use would apply here.  The example of `hoc tibi auxilior` strikes me as too much an abl. of means.  Mine is not a final answer, but my educated opinion is still that it cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me we're dealing with what I've usually seen mentioned as "relational accusative" or "Greek accusative", something that is usually restricted to pronouns and you could also find in the standard *interest* or *opus est* construction. When you encounter one, you are most likely able to render it as "concerning sth" (limitation), but I would not exclude other close possibilities, i.e. what one would expect the ablative to be used for (cause, means,...)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the Greek accusative (or *accusativus respectus*). I was actually thinking about an actual object like *illud* in *illud ei consentio*, but this answer is interesting. The Greek accusative appears to be narrower in scope than the corresponding ablative, so I wonder if the use you suggest would be idiomatic classical Latin.